# Recording raw audio from audio input in C++/Ubuntu

Tags: c++, audio, sampling

What is the easiest way to simply record the raw audio values from, say, the built in microphone on a laptop, to a text file in real time. I'd like to work in C++, but any language/method that accomplishes this would be fine as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice for C++ audio capture API under Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916113/best-practice-for-c-audio-capture-api-under-linux)

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you look into programming /dev/dsp.