# Virtual ALSA card, offering a capture interface with data received from another process

Tags: linux, audio, virtual, alsa, audio-capture

I need to create a virtual ALSA card, visible as a device with single capture interface, which I could configure for particular data format and sampling frequency, and then feed it with the data produced in the real time by another process.
The important requirement is that the latency should be as low as possible.

Has anybody solved similar problem, and could suggest the right solution?
**Update**
I have found two solutions which may be good templates:

1. The ALSA [snd-aloop](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix%3aModule-aloop) driver
2. The ALSA [snd-minivosc](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Minivosc) virtual oscilator

I hav yet to evaluate their applicability to my problem.

Comment: Does it really need to be at the ALSA level? Couldn't you use pulseaudio instead? I know nothing about this, I'm just suggesting a possible alternative approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice for C++ audio capture API under Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916113/best-practice-for-c-audio-capture-api-under-linux)

Comment: Pulseaudio is unacceptable due to too high latency.

Comment: So, what's the question? You've only stated what you'd like the end-result to be.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "produced"? Is the data generated by your program, or does it come from somewhere else?

Comment: In fact both options are possible. It can be either a process generating data or data received via radio link. I have found some possible solutions for both options - I've put them to the update of my question

Comment: wzab, are u able to simulate virtual capture interface in alsa?